# Trying to insert IP address but get an error

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to insert IP addresses into LastIP(An unsigned integer)

```
INSERT INTO user_entry (UPC, StateID, StoreID,CityID,Price,Count,LastIP) VALUES (885909301378,1,1,1,170,0,INET_ATON(127.0.0.1))
```

Error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.0.1))' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add quotes:

```
INSERT INTO user_entry
(UPC, StateID, StoreID,CityID,Price,Count,LastIP) VALUES 
(885909301378,1,1,1,170,0,INET_ATON("127.0.0.1"))
```

Source: [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)